# Issue with Form validation in React with React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Hello fellow developers,

I'm new to React and I'm having some troubles with form validation. I'm working on a CRUD app with API. When I update form fields the validation tells me that form input is required even if they have data already.

To replicate the issue, from the Read view just click on update button, on any record, and when you're inside the Update view click the Update Button without changing anything.

Screenshot -> https://ibb.co/zXXy5ML

APP -> [https://react-phonebook.vercel.app/](https://react-phonebook.vercel.app)

Source CODE -> https://github.com/alessiooli/react-phonebook

I read all the documentation and examples of React Hook Form but didn't find a solution. Since I'm a beginner in React it's hard to debug the issue all by myself.

EDIT: I think the issue could be in the way I implemented validation. When clicking **Update** it revalidate all the fields even if it's not necessary.

```
<input
        placeholder='First Name'
        required
        value={firstName}
        {...register("firstName", {
          onChange: (event) => setFirstName(event.target.value),
          required: "Required",
          pattern: {
            value: /^(?=.{1,40}$)[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-'\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$/,
            message: "invalid First Name",
          },
        })}
      />
```

Comment: Post the exact code where your issue is

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why do you add custom `onChange` handlers to the form elements, when RHF handles that out of the box? The validation for the Update flow fails because you don't set any default values for the form elements, so RHF thinks the form is empty. I recommend checking the RHF docs and particularly the [register](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/) section.

Comment: @Clarity Thank you, you were right. Setting default values fixed the problem of validation, but I'm not understanding how I can pass `(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)` without the onChange method. RHF documentation shows this way, the same as I did: 
`register('firstName', {
  onChange: (e) => console.log(e)
})`

Comment: RHF handles that for you. You just call `{...register('firstName')}` and when you submit the form, the `onSubmit` function argument will have the 'firstName' key with the entered input value.

Comment: @Clarity could you please provide a little example?

Comment: I have a proper tutorial here, which has plenty of examples: [Managing Forms with React Hook Form](https://claritydev.net/blog/managing-forms-with-react-hook-form).